# AngularJS - Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I have a problem with a bootstrap `datepicker`. Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fJiDJc1umtnR5veflaOP?p=preview) example.

This one is not from me. To get it working, you have to change line 60 into:

```
else if (attrs.initDate)
```

Just delete the exclamation mark.

Now you get the init-date in the 2nd input-field.

**My Problem:**

If you click in the 2nd input-field and click somewhere in the document without selecting a date, it changes the init-date into todays date. I want to keep the init date, dough.

Does anyone have a solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can look at the documentation here:
http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#forceparse

look at the **forceParse**, you need to set it to false.
so just add:

```
$(element).datepicker({
                        format: format,
                        forceParse: false
```